# AuthError - Username cannot be empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I created SignUp page for My React App,Later Im trying to store those SignUp Information in AWS Amplify, I follow the Documentation Steps to store SignUp Information in Amplify after finishing the Work,I expected all the information are stored Online,But That was Wrong.,I got Below ERROR

```
[ERROR] 55:29.258 AuthError - Username cannot be empty
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
SignUp.js:20 AuthError: Username cannot be empty
    at new AuthError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:10816:20)
    at AuthClass.rejectAuthError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:10734:27)
    at AuthClass.signUp (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:8550:19)
    at signUp (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1406:62)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:376157:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:376206:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:376266:35)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:376281:29)
    at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:380516:7)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:380548:11)
    at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:380561:9)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:380572:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:380783:16
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:394468:16)
    at batchedEventUpdates (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:375955:16)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:380782:7)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:378265:7)
    at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:378183:23)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:413814:16)
    at runWithPriority$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:383563:14)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:394485:18)
    at discreteUpdates (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:375967:16)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:378149:7)
 


Here Is The Code:



    import React,{useState} from 'react'
    import Amplify,{Auth} from 'aws-amplify'
    import awsconfig from "../SignProperties/aws-exports"
    Amplify.configure(awsconfig)
    function SignUp() {
        const initialValues={username:"",password:"",email:"",phoneNumber:""}
        const [loginAttributes,setLoginAttributes]=useState(initialValues)
        const onChange=(e)=>{
            setLoginAttributes({[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    
        }
        const signUp=async()=>{
            const {username,password,email,phoneNumber}=loginAttributes
            try{
                await Auth.signUp({username,password,attributes:{
                    email,phoneNumber
                }
            })
            console.log("Succesful")}
            catch(error){console.log(error)}
        }
        return (
            <div className="signUpScreen">
                <input onChange={onChange} name="username" placeholder="username" ></input>
                <input onChange={onChange} name="password" placeholder="password" type="password"></input>
                <input onChange={onChange} name="Email" placeholder="Email" type="email"></input>
                <input onChange={onChange} name="Phone_Number" placeholder="Phone_Number" type="number"></input>
                <button onClick={signUp}> Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default SignUp
```

Please Help to find Out The Error i have Done

Comment: You are getting this error because even though you are passing the variable `(username)`, it is always an empty value `("")`. You are never updating any of your variables.

Comment: const onChange=(e)=>{
            setLoginAttributes({[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    
        }  Bro is this wrong

Comment: try this, `const onChange=(e)=>{ setLoginAttributes({e.target.name:e.target.value}) } `

Comment: bro That one is Not Woring

Comment: Did you try to log `username,password` right before `Auth.signup`?
(`console.log(username,password)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not updating loginAttributes value, you are simply redefining the loginAttributes value.

First when you enter your user name you set the loginAttributes to {username : name}, then when you enter the password, you simply redefining the loginAttributes to {password: 'password'}, So it will remove the username property from loginAttributes.

So you can write like this in onChange function

```js
setLoginAttributes(prev => ({
  ...prev,
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value
})
```

what it will do is update the new value with previous loginAttributes values.